# Modal Chord Families

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, modes

Lately I came here with a question about modal II-V patterns and my answers were varied. I'm very confused about modal chord families and I can't find a single book or page on the internet anywhere. I'm trying to keep this short, if you have any questions just comment.

Some sort of chart would be incredibly helpful. For example, the ii of Phrygian acts like a dominant chord. And etc for all the other modes. I'm reading a Berklee college book that states chords built on the first, third, and sixth degree tend to be in the tonic family. Also, chords that contain the fourth of a scale tend to be sub-dominant. I was told The ii of Phrygian acts like a dominant chord because of the way it moves into the tonic, which sounds correct. But this chord contains the fourth of the scale so shouldnt it be sub-dominant? It states that it's the same for evey scale and i even copied the chart from the library. Im starting to work on it myself but any help would be appreciated for me to check over my work. Here's the page to my question if anyone is curious about the responses I got: [Modal II-V Patterns](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/62193/modal-ii-v-patterns/62242#62242)

Comment: Are you asking us if we know of any charts?

Comment: Well, yes. But if there are none available, how do you find them on your own? Of course you can use your ear but I'm just worried about my ear being a bit different from others. There was obviously some difference with the two people in that link I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the answers given in the your last thread I would suggest using an aug sixth chord to resolve to Phrygian tonic at some point. This will have the leading tone and have an overwhelming tendency to resolve to root position tonic but the resolution will feel rather unstable into a minor chord since the ear in the west will expect the i to become I or I7. Both of those would be rightfully notated as a V/iv. Therefore using this make for easy modulation to the relative aeolian off of the subdominant to your Phrygian tonal center.